# If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, isn't it false that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f(x)n^2 dx = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

A candidate that I have in mind is any piecewise function defined by a polynomial. Certainly such an integral of a function $f(x)n^2$ will not vanish as $n\to\infty$. What am I missing here if this is not the case?

Comment: Are you missing something here? You could pull the $n$ outside of the integral, and you will see that the limit $=0$ iff the integral of $f$ over $[0,1]$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Hyperion No, I didn't miss that at all. I realize that any functions whose integrals over $[0,1]$ is zero must vanish, but the claim I heard in class is that this is true for all Riemann integrable functions over $[0,1]$.

Comment: It is so obviously false that I am suspicious you heard that from a teacher. The most probable thing is that you missed something indeed.

Comment: @nicomezi after going back into my notes I have written $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx$ and when I compare that with my recording the professor says $\int_0^1 f(x)n^2 dx$. So I am guess she misspoke since it is written differently in my notes. I thought it was obvious too!

Comment: If your notes says otherwise then yes, you are probably right, just a mispoke.Happens .. :p

Comment: Will you then update the question accordingly?